# Creating a private "function" inside the class body in ES6 JS and hide it from the object's interface

Tags: javascript

I want to create a private function and place it inside the class body but NOT to return it to the object's prototype interface just like what I'm doing inside the constructor() function, please have a look:

```
class Circle {
    constructor(radius) {
        const _radius = radius;
        //see I'm not returning it to $this object!
    } 
    parseJSON(json) { //this should be a private function, only accessible inside the class body
        result = //.. do some magic
        return result;
    }
    draw(){
        const result = parseJSON("argument");
        return result;
    }
}
const c1 = new Circle(1);
console.dir(c1);
console.dir(Circle);
```

I want to apply the "abstraction" concept of object-oriented programming to this class by hiding the parseJSON() 'private' function from the object's prototype interface!

I want the output to look exactly the following:

```
c1: {
    //nothing!
    __proto__: {
        draw: function()
        //there is no parseJSON here!
    }
}
Circle: {
    //nothing!
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields  MDN is a great resource for these types of things.

Comment: The downvotes on the question don't mean anything to me, the private fields don't solve my problem. 

I want to hide the #parseJSON() method from the outside object interface, and not just to restrict accessing it

Comment: If it's not on the prototype, how would it be shared amongst instances of the class, for other methods to use?

Comment: Good question, this is why I'm asking for a way of doing it

Comment: And I'm asking, logically, since the methods on the prototype are how the classes are shared between instances, how would that be possible if the method is not on the prototype?

Comment: let's say through their constructor?

Comment: the private class fields are fixing half of the problem which is to prevent the outside guys (outside the class body) from modifying the classes' private fields but are not applying the principle of "abstraction" in object-oriented programming. what I am looking for is a way to achieve both things in that same time

Comment: @Taplar, answering your question after a little bit of thinking. I think that the answer is yes! through their own constructor, so in other words through their parent scope, because of the concept of closures in javascript

Comment: To use a shared method, without it being on the class prototype, it has to reside in a shared scope, such as 3limin4t0r answered below, or passed around through method chaining.  The usage of a shared scope is much different than it being defined by the class, but not on the class.

Answer (score 6):

Like stated in the [comments by Taplar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63833344/creating-a-private-function-inside-the-class-body-in-es6-js#comment112878220_63833344) you could use a [private class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields).

```
class Circle {
    constructor(radius) {
        this._radius = radius;
    } 
    #parseJSON(json) {
        return //.. do some magic
    }
    draw(){
        return this.#parseJSON("argument");
    }
}
```

<s>However this is currently an experimental feature.</s>

---

Old alternative:

If you'd like something that is currently supported you can play with scopes. Wrapping the whole class in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) would do the trick. This would create a new scope to hold the private functions.

```
const Circle = (function () {
  function parseJSON(json) {
    return // ... do some magic
  }

  return class {
    constructor(radius) {
      this._radius = radius;
    }
    draw() {
      return parseJSON("argument");
    }
  };
})();
```

Note that you can't access `this` inside your private functions, because it is not a property of your object. Pass all things you need through the arguments instead.

Comment: Oh! this is one of the solutions! but look at the code it's very polluted, aren't there any other simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: the private class fields are just restricting the access to the methods, but they're still showing inside the object's prototype interface, try to console.dir(Circle) after using the private class field on the #parseJSON, you'll see inside the output that the #parseJSON is still showing on the object's interface

Comment: 3limin4t0r, you're the only one I can see who can see the problem clearly, thanks for your comment, yes that's true, the only way to create a scope in javascript is to use a wrapping function.
do you think that this is a missed piece from the new es6 classes of javascript like me?

Comment: I misspoke, there is currently also [block-scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block), but that's a bit more tricky to work with. `let`/`const` and seemingly named classes are scoped at block level, while `var` and named functions are scoped to the nearest function.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function with var, for the private function.

```
class Circle {
 constructor() {

  var privateFunction = function() {
    // do something
  }
 }
 
}
```

Comment: That method would only be available inside the constructor method.

Comment: @Taplar, exactly

Comment: Please review the OP.  `parseJSON` in their case is shared.  They want it to be shared, but not put on the prototype

Comment: @Taplar let me observe the benefit of my idea of my question: the methods that are inside the prototype of the Circle All of them will need to use the parseJSON function, But ME (the consumer of the object) I don't need the parseJSON to be accessible from the outside of the class body scope, for example I don't need the parseJSON() function to be accessible from another class like Square class for example! this is (the parseJSON) is just a "utility" or a "tool" needed only inside the Circle class.